# How to highlight some lines in SyntaxHighlighter Evolved WordPress Plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins, syntax-highlighting, vim-syntax-highlighting, syntaxhighlighter

I am using  SyntaxHighlighter Evolved WordPress Plugin and I want to highlight some lines of code. How to do this?

Example in the below code. I have applied syntax highlighter for HTML brush (using shortcode). I have to highlight the lines 3 and 4, how to do it? Thanks.

[html]

Country:

Name: United States

State: New York

City: New York City

[/html]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `highlight` shortcode.

```
[html highlight="3-4"]
Country:
Name: United States
State: New York
City: New York City
[/html]
```